# how to fix this error on Dokan: "You can not add more than one vendors product in the cart"

Tags: dokan, multistore

I get the error on Dokan multistore and I already check on /general setting and selected multiple category and disable single seller mode but nothing works. Im really tired, I checked on internet and youtube and I do not find the problem.

I expect help from those who already have the problm and fix it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide [mcve] to clarify the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please deactivate the **Dokan PayPal Adaptive** Module in order to get rid of this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).